# CSS3 Transitions and WebKit Browsers

Tags: android, html, css, animation

The below `CSS Class` seems to work fine in the browser. But once I run it inside the Android browser. The object just snaps into place instead of animating.

`.ease {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
    -webkit-transition: transform  400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition: transform  400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}`

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Try this : `.ease {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform  400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition: transform  400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}`